# Faster android emulator on Linux

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, ubuntu

I started to use Android Studio 2.2, it all goes well but when I make run even just a simple Hello World app, it all crash down to super slow. I know that Linux kernel has KVM for accelerating virtual machines by default. To use KVM I just need the right permission to access /dev/kvm. Is it right?

what is the right permission? or am I walking to completely wrong way?

I downloaded Intel x86 Atom_64google_apis  but its has a broken sign, what does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Genymotion. On my Mac, Android emulator by Google is really slow, but Genymotion isn't. Its free version is limited, but if you're only experimenting with Android/writing simple apps, it will be enough for you.